# How to disable the refresh after show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basic form of the code is given below that i want rectified. while running the code once it reaches .show() function the page is getting refreshed. I don't want that. Can you help me with this dilemma!!!!
Please see the code below :

**Code:**

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mandate").hide();
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if(password=='') {
            $("#mandate").show();
        }
        else {
            alert("Form Submitted Successfully..!!");
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<p id="mandate"><font color="red">Password is mandatory*</font></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `return false;` to your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mandate").hide();
        $("#submit").click(function() {
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if(password=='') {
            $("#mandate").show();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
        alert("Form Submitted Successfully..!!");
        }
});
```

The return false will return false to the event. That tells the browser to stop following events, like follow a link. It is similar to [event.preventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: Please don't forget to include a little explication